# What is the direction of this path?

Tags: asymptote

```
import graph;
size(300);
pair O=(0.3,-1),M=(2,.5);
real f1(real x) {return 2*cos(x);}
path Cf1=graph(f1,-3.14,3.14,n=400);
path c1=circle(O,abs(O-M));
draw(Cf1^^c1,dashed);
pair[] t=intersectionpoints(Cf1,c1);
dot("$t[0]$",t[0],blue);
dot("$t[1]$",t[1],green);
dot("$t[2]$",t[2],red);
dot("$t[3]$",t[3],orange);
real[][] A = intersections(Cf1,c1);
path kn01=subpath(Cf1,A[0][0],A[1][0]); // true direction
path kn02=subpath(c1,A[1][1],A[0][1]); // CCW
path kn12=subpath(Cf1,A[1][0],A[2][0]); // true direction
path kn21=subpath(c1,A[2][1],A[1][1]); // CCW
path kn23=subpath(Cf1,A[2][0],A[3][0]); // true direction
path kn32=subpath(c1,A[3][1],A[2][1]); // CW !?
draw(kn01,arrow=Arrow,linewidth(1bp)+blue);
draw(kn02,arrow=Arrow,linewidth(1bp)+red);
draw(kn12,arrow=Arrow,linewidth(1bp)+blue);
draw(kn21,arrow=Arrow,linewidth(1bp)+red);
draw(kn23,arrow=Arrow,linewidth(1bp)+blue);
draw(kn32,arrow=Arrow,linewidth(1bp)+red);
```

[image]

Why?

My Asymptote version is 2.61.

Comment: `A[3][1]` is the beginning while `A[2][1]` is the end of the subpath so it is the normal behavior. Please observe that the `A[?][1]` are not ordered and that `c1` is a cyclic path. It is not possible to have ordered times for both `Cf1` and `c1`.

Comment: @O.G. Thanks for reminding! So this is true? `... path m1=cut(c1,Cf1,0).before; path m2=cut(c1,Cf1,3).after; draw(m1,2bp+green); draw(m2,2bp+blue); ... `.

Comment: Yes and you have to manage by yourself the 'cyclic' character of the c1.